# How to get the message length using ISO8583 library by Oscar Anderson?

Tags: c, iso8583

How can i geth the length of my isomsg using Oscar Anderson's C library
 Supposed i have this:

```
enter code here

DL_ISO8583_HANDLER isoHandler;
DL_ISO8583_MSG     isoMsg;
DL_UINT8           buf[MAX_DATASIZ];
DL_UINT16          bufSize;

DL_ISO8583_DEFS_1987_GetHandler(&isoHandler);

/* initialise ISO message */
DL_ISO8583_MSG_Init(NULL,0,&isoMsg);


(void)DL_ISO8583_MSG_SetField_Str(0,"0320",&isoMsg);
(void)DL_ISO8583_MSG_SetField_Str(2,"4401410145200145",&isoMsg); 
(void)DL_ISO8583_MSG_SetField_Str(3,"310000",&isoMsg);
(void)DL_ISO8583_MSG_SetField_Str(4,"000000001045",&isoMsg);
(void)DL_ISO8583_MSG_SetField_Str(11,"000015",&isoMsg);

(void)DL_ISO8583_MSG_Pack(&isoHandler,&isoMsg,&buf[7],&bufSize);
```

How can get my isoMsg length?

Comment: sizeof(isoMsg) ?

Comment: it is giving a big number which not the real length.

Comment: can you provide the definition of the struct DL_ISO8583_MSG ?

Comment: struct DL_ISO8583_MSG_S  
{  
    /* static memory details */  
    DL_UINT8 *sPtrNext; /* next static point - NULL if dynamic mode  */  
    DL_UINT8 *sPtrEnd;  /* end of the static buffer (if static mode) */  
  
    /* NB bitmap is not stored, it is implied if the field is set */  
  
    /* fields */  
    DL_ISO8583_MSG_FIELD field[1+kDL_ISO8583_MAX_FIELD_IDX];  
};  
typedef struct DL_ISO8583_MSG_S  DL_ISO8583_MSG;

Answer (score 0):

from what I see here is the definition of `DL_ISO8583_MSG`:

```
struct DL_ISO8583_MSG_S
{
    /* static memory details */
    DL_UINT8 *sPtrNext; /* next static point - NULL if dynamic mode  */
    DL_UINT8 *sPtrEnd;  /* end of the static buffer (if static mode) */

    /* NB bitmap is not stored, it is implied if the field is set */

    /* fields */
DL_ISO8583_MSG_FIELD field[1+kDL_ISO8583_MAX_FIELD_IDX];
};
typedef struct DL_ISO8583_MSG_S DL_ISO8583_MSG;
```

just parse through the `DL_UINT8 pointers` and store the count into a variable.

Comment: can you add comment on your code because I don't understand the use of it. Thx